# CRM 2011 Passing QueryString to SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a report in SSRS that I have in Dynamics CRM 2011 and when the report is run, in the url it passes the id like `http://url&id=123-123-123-123`. I am trying to make my report in ssrs to grab the id from the query string and use that in the parameters to determine which data to show. Is this possible and if so how would one go about doing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRM actually sends a parameter which can be used to select the filtered view of data that the report was run on.  See the [report writers guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955081), and in particular, [Using Filters in a Report.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955092.aspx)

In the simplest case, you would write your main data set to select like so: `SELECT <column1>, <column2>, <columnN> FROM FilteredAccount AS CRMAF_FilteredAccount`

If that doesn't answer answer your question... You could write an aspx page which embeds the report viewer control.  From there you would read the query string, load the report, and then set some parameters based on the query string values.  You'd have to have custom ribbon options to launch your custom page.

Comment: Thanks, I really just need to read the QueryString. Right now CRM passes the ID I need in the QueryString when you click the Run report button. I just need to read that and use it as a report parameter.

Comment: It's the ID of the Project you are on in CRM.

Comment: So some entity like new_project?

Comment: Yea, project is an entity I have. And ID is the ID of the different records inside project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

[Here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/crmdevelopment/thread/741ff057-94d8-4431-b831-610e035b7f9f) is the resolution which worked for me: